# Linux IP tables on Open-WRT: forwarding vs stateful packet filtering

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, openwrt

I followed the Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook, 5th edition's complete example for iptables.  The stateful packet filtering has allowed me to print remotely on my MakerBot, but I could not connect to my home server via SSH today.  The SysAdmin Handbook says that stateful packet filtering is the most powerful feature that Netfilter brings to firewalling, but that it may add unneeded complexity to a network.  Hence, I will probably cut my losses with stateful packet filtering unless someone can cut the Gordian knot.

IPtables -L -v output:

```
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             icarus.lan           tcp dpt:ssh
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             icarus.lan           tcp dpt:www
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             icarus.lan           tcp dpt:https
```

23M   21G ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

For some reason Open-WRT/LEDE resets my default INPUT policy to accept even after I set it to DROP.  However, that rule does not seem match anything so I'm not too concerned.  You can see above I have packet forwarding set for SSH but that rule is not matching anything. Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: If you just want to make some ports (ssh, printing) on some computers in your home network visible to the outside (provided your ISP has given you a public IP, and is not using NAT), [port forwarding](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/port.forwarding) may be simpler than a manual firewall configuration. If your ISP does carrier-grade NAT, don't expect this to work (or use IPv6).

Comment: In the short run port forwarding would be easier, but I'm not sure that it would be easier in the long run.   The intersection between the interface of the four routers that I have set up for port forwarding for SSH, www, printing, is little: port forwading is always listed in a different place on the web browser interface and one router calls it "service mangement" instead.  However, under the hood, I'm pretty sure they all use iptables.

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting this morning, I managed to open port 22, but with the caveat that my default policy is ACCEPT.  I can only SSH into my router, not my server (Icarus).  Obviously with IPv6, I could connect directly to Icarus, but there's only one coffeeshop with IPv6 in town.  Neither of these are acceptable in the long run, so I still welcome advice, but for the short run my config is acceptable.

Comment: Erm, you don't want your router open to the wild on 22. Does said router support port translation?

Comment: IPtables support PAT.  Some texts might call it NAT.

Comment: The fact that whenever I err on the side of too secure while at a cafe, I lose SSH connection is significantly slowing down how many configurations I can iterate through in a week.  I thought that I could mimic an outside connection by using my phone's hotspot, but sometimes I can connect via SSH using my hotspot but cannot at a cafe which does not make sense to me.

Comment: Hmm, I guess this would depend on the hotspot. Some of the ones in my area (captive portal style) will only allow port 53, 80 & 443 outbound on the network. Maybe try hosting the SSH connection on another port. Or VPN into a box that you know can reach the devices you need to configure.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that my mobile hotspot connected to my server from within the LAN is because I neglected to turn off WiFi on my smartphone. I realized that instead of trying to figure directly manipulate iptables it would be much easier to set up port forwarding in the browser then SSH into the router and run iptables -L -v to see what had changed in the backend.  Since the changes are in the pre and postrouing, the aforementioned command didn't show any changes afterwards, so I had to run iptables -t nat -L to see what had changed.